# Getting max row from multi-index table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table that looks similar to this:

| user_id | date | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020 | 5 |
|  | 2021 | 7 |
| 2 | 2017 | 1 |
| 3 | 2020 | 2 |
|  | 2019 | 1 |
|  | 2021 | 3 |

I'm trying to keep only the row for each user_id that has the greatest count so it should look like something like this:

| user_id | date | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021 | 7 |
| 2 | 2017 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021 | 3 |

I've tried using df.groupby(level=0).apply(max) but it removes the date column from the final table and I'm not sure how to modify that to keep all three original columns

Comment: A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help the answerer and would get you an answer quicker

Answer (score 1):

You can try to specify only column `count` after `.groupby()` and then use `.apply()` to generate the boolean series whether the current entry in a group is equal to max `count` in group.  Then, use `.loc` to locate the boolean series and display the whole dataframe.

```
df.loc[df.groupby(level=0)['count'].apply(lambda x: x == x.max())]
```

**Result:**

```
         date  count
user_id             
1        2021      7
2        2017      1
3        2021      3
```

Note that if there are multiple entries in one `user_id` that have the same greatest count, all these entries will be kept.

In case for such multiple entries with greatest count you want to keep only one entry per `user_id`, you can use the following logics instead:

```
df1 = df.reset_index()
df1.loc[df1.groupby('user_id')['count'].idxmax()].set_index('user_id')
```

**Result:**

```
         date  count
user_id             
1        2021      7
2        2017      1
3        2021      3
```

Note that we *cannot* simply use `df.loc[df.groupby(level=0)["count"].idxmax()]` because `user_id` is the row index.  This code only gives you all unfiltered rows just like the original dataframe unprocessed. This is because the index that `idxmax()` returns in this code is the `user_id` itself (instead of simple RangeIndex 0, 1, 2, ...etc). Then, when  `.loc` locates these `user_id` index, it will simply return *all* entries under the same `user_id`.

### Demo

Let's add more entries to the sample data and see the differences between the 2 solutions:

Our base `df` (`user_id` is the row index):

```
         date  count
user_id             
1        2018      7                 <=== max1
1        2020      5
1        2021      7                 <=== max2
2        2017      1
3        2020      3                 <=== max1
3        2019      1
3        2021      3                 <=== max2
```

**1st Solution result:**

```
df.loc[df.groupby(level=0)['count'].apply(lambda x: x == x.max())]


         date  count
user_id             
1        2018      7
1        2021      7
2        2017      1
3        2020      3
3        2021      3
```

**2nd Solution result:**

```
df1 = df.reset_index()
df1.loc[df1.groupby('user_id')['count'].idxmax()].set_index('user_id')


         date  count
user_id             
1        2018      7
2        2017      1
3        2020      3
```

Comment: @Ben.T  That's the case in this logics.   Just let OP's see whether this is what he/she wants.

Comment: @Ben.T  Thanks for the comment!  I've edited my answer to highlight that multiple entries of the same highest count will be extracted.  Also giving new solution that will keep only one entry.  Just let OP choose base on his/her needs.